# vscode format save singline

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I get to one line just like before saving?

I want to use formatOnSave

ex) vscode before save

```
html, body {height:100%}
```

ex) vscode after save

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do have any formatter extensions especially prettier, etc. installed?  I don't and vscode doesn't change your example code for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line in your user settings.

Preferences > Settings

```js
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 120 // any width you like
```